# Javascript or jQuery help

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my website: http://keironlowe.x10hosting.com/

I need to know how to make the red line slowly get longer when hovering over, and slowly shrink back to normal size afterwards using javascript or jQuery.

Could someone show me something to get started in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) to do something to an element, which includes a duration parameter that defines how long it should take for the animation to complete. Then there's the [`hover`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) function which takes a set of functions. So this is the general idea:

```
$('div', '#nav_container').hover(function() {
    // this gets called on hover
    $(this).animate({width: 'XXXpx'}, 10000); // 10000 = 10 seconds        
}, function() {
    // this gets called on mouseout
    $(this).animate({width: 'XXXpx'}, 10000); // 10000 = 10 seconds
});
```

**EDIT**:

As far as your comment, if the code is in the `<HEAD>`, you need to wrap the code in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put the code you tried here
});
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this working.

Ive got <br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('div', '#nav_container').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: '230px'}, 10000); //      
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({width: '203px'}, 10000); 
});
</script>

Comment: Um,  take away that <br> at the start

Comment: Its working but ive got problems. 
I want to increase size when I hover over it, and when I take my cursor away it goes back to normal size
But the code makes it increase and then go back to normal on hover. 

It also only works once. I have to refresh for it to work again

Comment: Do you have the code uploaded on the URL in your question? I'd have to see it there to be able to debug further.

Comment: It also doesnt work on the home link

Comment: Got anywhere with that problem?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$('#nav_container div').hover(
    function(){$(this).find('img').animate({width:'100%'},{queue:false,duration:500});},
    function(){$(this).find('img').animate({width:'auto'},{queue:false,duration:500});}
);
```